# How to see that $\mathbb Q (z_1,\ldots,z_n, \bar z_1,\ldots, \bar z_n)$ is closed under conjugation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

How to see that if $z_i \in \mathbb C$ then $\mathbb Q (z_1,\ldots,z_n, \bar z_1,\ldots, \bar z_n)$ is closed under conjugation? The claim is made in a proof that a number is constructible from $z_i$ iff it's in some square root tower over the above field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\{z_1,\ldots,z_n,\overline{z_1},\ldots,\overline{z}_n\}$ are closed under conjugation and recall that $\mathbb{Q}(z_1,\ldots,z_n,\overline{z_1},\ldots,\overline{z}_n)$ is the smallest field containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and  $\{z_1,\ldots,z_n,\overline{z_1},\ldots,\overline{z}_n\}$.

Comment: I still can't see it. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Let $K:=\{\overline{z};z\in\mathbb{Q}(z_1,\ldots,z_n,\overline{z_1},\ldots,\overline{z_n})\}$, it is a field containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\{z_1,\ldots,z_n,\overline{z_1},\ldots,\overline{z_n}\}$ and hence $\mathbb{Q}(z_1,\ldots,z_n,\overline{z_1},\ldots,\overline{z_n})$.

Comment: Aha. Nice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Concretely, the field $\Bbb Q(z_1,...,z_n,\bar z_1,...,\bar z_n)$ consists of all rational functions (i.e. quotients of polynomials) in $z_1,...,z_n,\bar z_1,...,\bar z_n$ with rational coefficients.

Since complex conjugation fixes the coefficients and interchanges $z_i$ with $\bar z_i$, it transforms a rational function in $z_1,...,z_n,\bar z_1,...,\bar z_n$ into another.